# Scrollview gives error in android

Tags: android, uiscrollview, scrollview

Hello i am trying to add scrollview to my layout but it gives me error scrollview can host only one direct child. I want to scroll only edittext not a imageviev and button button both need to be constants. And when i am rotating my device to landscape contains are not displays. please give the solution for this

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#aeabab"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarforprofile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:titleTextColor="#000"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/icon_car" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="CAR PREFERENCE"
        android:textColor="#111"
        android:textSize="17dp" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/icon_location"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:hint="WHERE TO GO" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="FROM DATE"
            android:textColor="#111"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/icon_calendar"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:hint="30/05/2017" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="TO DATE"
            android:textColor="#111"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/icon_calendar"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:hint="30/05/2017" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/icon_clock"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:hint="10 AM" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/icon_people"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:hint="NUMBER OF PERSON"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLines="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="CAR TYPE"
            android:textColor="#111"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="SEDDAN" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="HACHBACK" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="SUV" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-57dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleX="0.9"
        android:scaleY="0.9">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_green"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="ORDER NOW"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you just want to scroll the EditText, put its height to wrap_content and it will automatically scroll and remove the scroll View

Answer (score 0):

You can place one direct child to `ScrollView` which is true at least to current latest API. You have `LinearLayout` and multiple `EditText`s as a direct child of `ScrollView`, which leads to crash.

You can wrap your multiple `View`s in `ViewGroup` which can be `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout` or a `FrameLayout` but make sure `ScrollView` have always one direct child.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    .....
    .....

     <LinearLayout

     <EditText

     <EditText

     <TextView

     .....
     .....

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Try this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/icon_location"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:hint="WHERE TO GO" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="FROM DATE"
                android:textColor="#111"
                android:textSize="17dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/icon_calendar"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:hint="30/05/2017" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="TO DATE"
                android:textColor="#111"
                android:textSize="17dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/icon_calendar"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:hint="30/05/2017" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/icon_clock"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:hint="10 AM" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/icon_people"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:hint="NUMBER OF PERSON"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLines="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:text="CAR TYPE"
                android:textColor="#111"
                android:textSize="17dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="SEDDAN" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:text="HACHBACK" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="SUV" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: where i can place scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Your `NestedScrollView` can only have one direct child as the error message states. You have several direct children, so that won't work.

To fix this, you can wrap all of the direct children of the `NestedScrollView` in a `LinearLayout`. That will give the scroll view just one child: the new `LinearLayout`.

`LinearLayout` is just one `ViewGroup` you can use, but it is probably the most appropriate in this case.